# .NET Core EF Core 2 Models in 1 View Create Operation

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, ef-core-2.1

Hi I have read alot but couldn't really figure out how this is suppose to work out. 
Following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/intro?view=aspnetcore-2.0) tutorial, I couldn't quite figure out how to input data into 2 models at once with a Foreign Key mapping done properly.

Supposedly I have to 2 models (following the tutorial), for example student and enrollment and I want to input data to both tables at the same time, looking at other stack overflow posts, I found out that are 2 ways to incorporate 2 views into the model, either by creating a "big view" or using partial view which I have done in this case. So by returning 2 objects to the controller and having it saved to the DB as shown below, it works, except that Enrollment doesn't have any link with Student via studentID (Foreign Key). Is there a way to set it or bind it together?

Currently I can save both individual set of data to the DB. I just cannot seem to figure out how to set the foreign key.

What I have now in 2 DBs is

```
Student      | Enrollment
ID LastName    ID <Some Column> StudentID
1  XXX         1  XXX           NULL (Need this to be 1)
```

How do I get StudentID to be 1?

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("ID,LastName")] Student student, [Bind("<Some data inside enrollment>")] Enrollment enrollment)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _context.Add(student);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                _context.Add(enrollment);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return View(student);
        }
```

Thank you very much! Your help is much appreciated! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would help,

```
var resultStudent = _context.Add(student);
enrollment.student_id = resultStudent.id;
_context.Add(enrollment);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

or

```
enrollment.Student = student;
_context.Enrollments.Add(enrollment);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me. For the first example, I have some errors with enrollment.student_id = resultStudent.id; where I think it can't find resultStudent.id, while in the 2nd one, enrollment.Student = student; enrollment.Student is giving some errors

Comment: Without looking into your classes it is hard to understand what is wrong with your code

Comment: So sorry about that. Yep it is fixed and I have updated with an edit to your answer. Thanks for pointing in the right direction. Didn't know that I could still set the variables inside the controller. Thanks so much for your help once again! :)

Comment: you are welcome. If you feel that this answer is helpfull please consider to mark it as answer by checking green tick, so that community can benefit from it. good luck

Comment: Sure done it. Please take a look at my answer too. Thank you very much for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Modified Simonare answer a bit and this worked for me. Seems like var resultStudent isn't required, but the general idea of setting the ID inside the controller is there.

```
_context.Add(student);
enrollment.studentID = student.ID;
_context.Add(enrollment);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```